# Expired passport with current Tier 2 General visa

Tags: visas, uk

I have a Tier 2(General) UK visa with BRP card separately issued. My passport is expiring in 6 months time and I need to renew it soon. Do I have to inform UK immigration that I have a new passport?

Answer (score 1):

From the official UK Government web site:

> You don’t have to transfer your visa - you can carry both your old and new passports when travelling to or from the UK instead.

You can [transfer your visa](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) to your new passport if you wish, but this costs money. Because carrying both passports is free, you might not wish to spend the money.

Remember to inform your country's passport service that you need the old passport returned because it has valid visas in it.